# Замена пути в ссылке на картинку

Tags: jquery, javascript

```
    index=$(".previewphoto ul li").index(this);     
    curimg=$(".previewphoto ul li img").eq(index).attr("src");  


    $(".bigphoto img").attr("src",curimg);
```

В галереи, по клику на маленькую превьюшку меняется большая картинка. У маленьких картинок ссылка [index]_small.jpg, а большая [index]_big.jpg. Пока сделал что по клику на превьюшку передает атрибут ссылки. Как сделать замену атрибута _small на _big. где [index] у всех разный. например:
3123123123123123_small.jpg

3123123123123123_big.jpg[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это делается проще и без всяких классов:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.previewphoto ul li img').click(function () {
        var path = $(this).attr('src');
        var bigPath = path.substring(0, (path.indexOf('small')));
        $(this).attr('src', bigPath + 'big.jpg');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('img.small').click(fucntion(){
    $('#big').attr('src', this.src.replace('small.jpg', 'big.jpg'));
});
```

У маленьких картинок `class="small"`, у большой `id="big"`.